# System.IO.File missing an assembly reference

Tags: file, .net-4.5, .net

I'm trying to read text file using `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines`-method but an error pops up saying

> The type or namespace 'File' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?

I'm working with .Net Framework 4.5 and VS2012.

Comment: The specific project template you selected matters a great deal.  You cannot use the File class in Windows Store or PCL projects.

Comment: Exactly this is the case i'm facing, because i'm building Windows Store App

Answer (score 1):

That assembly is not available to you when building Windows Store (UWP) apps.

Instead, there is a [different mechanism you must use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/). This mechanism encourages a more modern view of file I/O that embraces asynchronous (non-blocking) access the use of buffers and libraries, as well as support for more kinds of devices that may not use traditional file paths.

Answer (score 0):

First go to **Solution Explorer** and Expand **References** and check whether **System** assembly is there in the list.

If you don't have it there, right click references and click **add Reference** and from the **.NET** tab, add **System** assembly

Now you should have **System** in the References list.

Now you can import the namespace System.IO as

```
using System.IO;
```

Note that **File**  is a class in namespace **System.IO**

So just use the File class in the code as follows.

```
File f = new File();//or whatever
```

I know the last line is sufficient but put down the whole thing for the completion. ;)

Comment: I am seeing it listed but when I attempt to add it I get an error indicating it's looking for a .NET 4.0 installation (which I don't have -- .NET 4.5 only):

Error loading code-completion information for System.IO from        C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO\4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.IO.dll:
Could not find assembly file.

Do I have roll back to 4.0 to get the System.IO reference to load properly?

Comment: This is for a Windows Store app. You can't use that assembly with that kind of app. There is a different mechanism for handling files in UWP apps, because the UWP does not allow you to have direct access to the file system via paths.